# How can I filter and exclude 1 item type in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects with categories. I need to grab all of the categories except for one that I can define manually. I've set that category up in my state. I want the `notCat` excluded.

So to get all of the objects, I have this:

```
state = {
    collapse: false,
    active: false,
    category: 'General Questions',
    notCat: 'Deal FAQ',
};
const cats = [...new Set(Faqs.map(q => q.category))];
    const catsR = cats.map((name, i) => {
        return (
            <li
                key={i}
                onClick={() => this.faqNavigation(name)}
                className={
                    this.state.category === name ? 'active' : 'not-active'
                }
            >
                {name}
            </li>
        );
    });
```

Then I'm simply rendering it like this:

```
<ul className="toc">{catsR}</ul>
```

How can I exclude a certain category. Say `Category A` in the `{catsR}` render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Faqs is an array there is really no need to convert it into a set and then into an array afterwards. Array.map already returns a new array so you could simply do:

```
const cats = Faqs.map(q => q.category);
```

As a response to your question you can use the Array.filter method to filter out certain categories before mapping it:

```
const catsR = cats.filter(c => c !== 'notCat').map((name, i) => {
    return (
        <li
            key={i}
            onClick={() => this.faqNavigation(name)}
            className={
                this.state.category === name ? 'active' : 'not-active'
            }
        >
            {name}
        </li>
    );
});
```